# cloud9 ide segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, debian, cloud9-ide

```
I am launching Cloud9 IDE on debian wheezy by command:

node local/cloud9/bin/cloud9.js --ip <ip> -w project/
and the output is:

  info  - socket.io started


                       Ajax.org Cloud9 IDE
                          version 0.5.1
Project root is: project/
Point your browser to http://<ip>:3000
```

but whenever i hit that url in browser, it immediately crashes with :

> Segmentation fault

leaving on browser

> Loading...

can i get any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault on node usually happens when trying to load binary components compiled for older different version of node.
either delete all `.node` files

or if you are running cloud9 version from https://github.com/c9/core reinstall node modules with

```
rm -rf node_modules/ ; 
git checkout -- node_modules/ ;
rm -rf node_modules/ --production ;
```